# CakePHP 2.x ACL Issues getting it working

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I have been trying to get the CakePHP ACL's working with my new application, it is causing me a world of pain. For some reason the ACL doesnt seem to be working however the tutorials are rubbish and don't explain each component very well. e.g. how a ACO links to a controller / function / views

I have got the ACL working correctly up until getting the pages to know if the user is allowed to view it, also same issue with menu items that they can / cant see.

I have noticed that if i add this code to my page the array shows the group as blank:

```
$user = $this->Auth->user(); 
pr($user);
```

The array returned:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 80
    [first_name] => Bob
    [last_name] => Test
    [email] => email@emial.com
    [username] => TestAdmin
    [tokenhash] => cleared
    [is_active] => 1
    [created] => 2014-10-03 16:32:45
    [modified] => 2014-10-03 16:32:45
    [token_expires_at] => 
    [group_id] => 3
    [Group] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [name] => 
            [enabled] => 
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 
        )

)
```

The site is basically a portal, visitors should only have access to login / register. and the users groups all have access to the dashboard however it ends up in a continuous loop unless i allow everyone access to the dashboard (due to the group not being recognised i guess)

any help would be appreciated, I realise that you may need me to post the code im using so please let me know what you would require.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I have updated my AppController as below and it has started showing the group in the array as it should!!! weird thanks for the push in the right direction.

AppController.php

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeRender() {
        if((($this->params['controller']==='Users') || ($this->params['controller']==='users'))&&(($this->params['action']=='login') || ($this->params['action']=='register') || ($this->params['action']=='success') || ($this->params['action']=='forgot_password') || ($this->params['action']=='reset_password')) ){
            $this->theme = 'DataHouseLogin';
        }else{
            $this->theme = 'DataHouse';
        }
        parent::beforeRender();
    }

    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'RequestHandler',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar' => array('panels' => array('history' => false)),
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array(
                    'actionPath' => 'controllers'
                    )
            ), 
            'loginAction' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users', 
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Dashboard',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        //$this->Auth->allowedActions = array('display','index','register');
        $this->set('user', $this->Auth->user());    
        $this->set('acl', $this->Acl);
        $this->Auth->authorize = array(
            'Controller',
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        ); 


        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Default deny
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you configured ACL and Auth components ? Show me your AppController->beforeFilter() function please.

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, i have added the beforeFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to configure Auth component correctly. Try to put this code in your AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
 public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session',
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
  );  

 public function beforeFilter() {
   $this->Auth->authorize = array(
        'Controller',
        'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
  );    
   $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'name', 'password' => 'password')));
   $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false);
   $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => false, 'plugin' => false);
 }

 public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Default deny
    return false;
 } 
}
```

EDIT:
in UserModel and GroupModel add act as property:

```
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));
```

in UserModel setup parentNode function:

```
public function parentNode() {
  if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
      return null;
  }
  if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
      $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
  } else {
      $groupId = $this->field('group_id');
  }
  if (!$groupId) {
      return null;
  } else {
      return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
  }
}
```

Comment: I have changed that and now can no longer login to the app

Comment: You should setup your ACL first correctly, It is possible to use Auth Component without ACL, but in this case you have to put Authorisation logic in isAuthorised function manually. Read [this - auth example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) article and it will be more clear to you

Comment: hmm yes well I did follow this and before I started to implement ACL it all worked very well then the ACL just doesnt seem to apply.

Comment: Ok I have managed to get the array to pick-up the group as expected. My next question is: How do I tell my controller e.g. DashboardController that it is linked to ACO DashboardController?

Comment: $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller' ....  does the trick...  But there are also some other stuff you need to setup, the best solution is to use [AclManager](https://github.com/FMCorz/AclManager) plugin - it will help you get it done